# What mechanics exist that trigger Burning Vengeance?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Burning Vengeance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burning%20Vengeance) is an enchantment that states:

> Whenever you cast a spell from your graveyard, Burning Vengeance deals
> 2 damage to target creature or player.

I know the Flashback keyword will activate Burning Vengeance, but the Oracle text on Gatherer leads me to believe that there are other ways to trigger its ability.  What other mechanics exist **in Modern** that will trigger Burning Vengeance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-flashback options include:

- (Standard/Modern) Creatures you can cast from the graveyard, like [Gravecrawler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222902) and [Havengul Lich](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262852).
- (Modern) Retrace cards like [Raven's Crime](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=153487), [Worm Harvest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=151135), [Flame Jab](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=153432).
- (Modern) [Haakon, Stromgald Scourge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=122045), especially played with Tribal cards like [Nameless Inversion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=143388) -- [**this is a "real" Modern deck**](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/deck/898), although not "tier 1".
- (Modern) [Toshiro Umezawa](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74431), although really that's flashback by another name.
- (Modern) [Chandra Ablaze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=195402).

Overall I feel like it plays best in a "Jund"-style deck (basically a huge pile of two-for-ones, building up card advantage incrementally while pressuring the opponent to keep tempo). In particular, I could see using Burning Vengeance in place of Seismic Assault in an [Aggro Loam](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/deck/837) variant that doesn't mind losing a little bit of speed for card advantage -- pitching a land to Raven's Crime and getting your Burning Vengeance trigger only cost {B} more than pitching it to Seismic Assault, but you get to force your opponent to discard.

I don't like trying to combo out in one turn with Burning Vengeance because I feel like it's weaker than [Pyromancer's Swath](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136216) in that kind of deck.

Comment: Added the modern stipulation to keep this narrowed some and because that's what I'm looking at more

Answer (score 2):

[Retrace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20%5Bretrace%5D) is another keyword that would activate Burning Vengeance.

[image: Cenn's Enlistment]

Also, [Toshiro](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74431)!

[image: Toshiro Umezawa]

But perhaps the perfect match with Burning Vengeance is unsurprisingly, [Chandra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=195402):

[image: Chandra Ablaze]

Other cards I found: [Gravecrawler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222902), [Karador, Ghost Chieftain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=236468)
, [Sins of the Past](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83648), [Skaab Ruinator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230780), and [Worldheart Phoenix](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=175401)

I *think* [Yawgmouth's Agenda](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23054) should work as well, although unlike most other cards, in the Oracle text "play" wasn't replaced with "cast".

Comment: In current Magic terminology, "play" means "play a land or cast a spell". So, yeah, it's all good.

Comment: @AlexP Oh yes, that's why Yawgmouth's Agenda's text wasn't changed — it still lets you play lands from the graveyard as if they're in your hand.